# What is this rhythm?

Tags: rhythm

I think I've heard this rhythm before, what is it called? Where does it come from?

[image: dah dah dit-dit dah dit-dit-dit-dah dit-dah]

Comment: I'm sure we all know it, but, yes, where's it from..? 1st bar is cha-cha!

Comment: That's the rhythm country western dancers use for cha-cha. The Latin dancers have the eighth notes on weak beats (2 and 4).  There's a similar difference in steps between East Coast and West Coast salsa or mambo dancers.  Geographic differences seem common among dancers in the US. Western Swing has the Push and Whip versions in Dallas and Houston respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Laurence shows, it's prevalent in pop culture as a crowd-participation chant. I'm used to it with the last two notes spoken as "Let's Go." It looks like it originated with a 1962 song by The Routers:

It looks like the opening clap/call material spread to cheerleading rather than the other way around. You can see more about its creation in the book [Superstar in a Masquerade](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Superstar_in_a_Masquerade/vT86EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=routers%20let%27s%20go&pg=PT970&printsec=frontcover) by William Sargent

Answer (score 1):

I've heard it at football matches, the first 9 notes stomped or clapped, the last two being a shouted team name.   [image]

Comment: i'm no football fan, but I first heard this in the early/mid 70's as M. I. - M.I.C. - M.I.C.K.-  Mick Jones. (Leeds Utd, back when they were good;)

Comment: Makes it hard for Wolverhampton Wanderers and others of such ilk!!!

Comment: Duh, duh. Duh, duh, duh. Duh, duh, duh, duh: Inverness Caledonian Thistle!!

Comment: Huh-huh-huh, ARSE-nal, huh-huh-huh